# The gotten state of a video does not match its typed out string value in a if function

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc

The console shows "State.Playing" throughout the video and "State.Ended" after the video ends but it won't get into the if function.

My guess is this is the bla = player.get_state() request gives a non-compatible format like bytes but no amount of me trying converts the string into anything the if function recognizes as the same as my typed value.

Thanks for the help

```
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer(fily) 
print("check0")
player.play()
while True:
    bla = player.get_state()
    print(bla)
       if bla == "State.Ended":
            print(player.get_state())
            print("checky")
            break
player.stop()
```

Comment: Right now you have a syntax error from incorrect indentation.

Comment: @eyllanesc's answer is spot on but you could just use `if bla == 6:` (0= None, 1=Opening, 2=Buffering, 3=Playing, 4=Paused, 5=Stopped, 6=Ended, 7=Error)

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Using numbers makes the code less readable, so it should not be used or recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_state()`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#get_state) does not return a string but a [`State`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.State-class.html):

```
import vlc

player = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename) 
print("check0")
player.play()
while True:
    if player.get_state() == vlc.State.Ended:
        print(player.get_state())
        print("checky")
        break
player.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't even aware states were a thing or could appear to be strings.